# How many paths does a nested if statement have?

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements, metrics

I have a question regarding this [metric](https://de.mathworks.com/help/bugfinder/ref/numberofpaths.html).

For example, if I have the following code, how many path does the function `main` have?

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            for (k=0; k<10; k++)
            {
                if (i < 2 )
                    printf("value is more than 2\n");
                if (i > 5)
                    printf("value is less than 5\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first three for loops should have 3 paths and one additional that bypasses all control flow statements, then what about the nested if statement? Is it 1x1 = 1 path?

Anyone without matlab account, the following description is on the website:

```
A control flow statement introduces branches and adds to the original one path.

    if-else if-else: Each if keyword introduces a new branch. The contribution from an if-else if-else block is the number of branches plus one (the original path). If a catch-all else is present, all paths go through the block; otherwise, one path bypasses the block.

    For instance, a function with an if(..) {} else if(..) {} else {} statement has three paths. A function with one if() {} only has two paths, one that goes through the if block and one that bypasses the block.

for and while: Each loop statement introduces a new branch. The contribution from a loop is two - a path that goes through the loop and a path that bypasses the loop.
If more than one control flow statement are present in a sequence without any nesting, the number of paths is the product of the contributions from each control flow statement.

For instance, if a function has three for loops and two if-else blocks, one after another, the number of paths is 2 × 2 × 2 × 2 × 2 = 32.

void func()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            for (k=0; k<10; k++)
            {
                if (i < 2 )
                    ;
                else
                {
                    if (i > 5)
                        ;
                    else
                        ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In this example, func has six paths: three from the for statements, two from the if statements plus the original path that bypasses all control flow statements.
```

Comment: your metric link goes to the login page of Matlab.

Comment: @Mairon oh yeah, we need to have an account to see the website. Should I upload photos from the website or what should I do?

Comment: @naomikim Copy-paste the question here as text. Images are not recommended.

Comment: 3 paths... a) print "value is more than 2" or b) print "value is less than 5" or c) do nothing. BTW: notice how the printed test contradicts the condition in the if-statement... hmm...

Comment: please see description I have just edited. Thank you

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something, this is not a nested if but just 2 separate ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description:

> If more than one control flow statement are present in a sequence without any nesting, the number of paths is the product of the contributions from each control flow statement.

and

> The contribution from an if-else block is the number of branches plus one (the original path)

your two if statements contribute 2 paths each, so that's 2 x 2 = 4 paths, and then each of your loop contributes one additional path, so the total would be 7 paths.

However, this description does not make much sense to me, since this code has only one possible path:

```
if (true) {
    // this part is always executed
}
```

This can seem obvious, but more complicated situations can easily reduce the number of possible paths, just like in your example where there are only three possibilities: either `i < 2` or `i > 5` or `i >= 2 && i <= 5`.

I suppose the metric's description would make sense as an upper bound on the number of paths.

Comment: "...is the product of the contributions from each control flow statement" and "your two if statements contribute 2 paths each, so that's 2 x 2 = 4 paths" hmm... I don't think that's correct here. The two if-statements are not independent so there can't be 4 paths. In this case there can never be a situation where both if-conditions are true

Comment: @SupportUkraine I don't see any mention of independence in the description. I'm following it to the letter. I do however explain how it's not entirely correct right after that sentence.